# SQL Compare 2 columns from 2 tables to complete another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

The tables have the following columns:

```
Table A: 
TIN, 
Fee_Sched, 
Effective_Date

Table B: 
TIN, 
Fee_Sched, 
Fee_Sched_Eff
```

TableB.Fee_Sched & TableB.Fee_Sched_Eff are currently blank

**This is what I want to do:**

I want to compare the two TIN columns and when there is a match, I want the corresponding results from TableA.Fee_Sched to print in TableB.Fee_Sched and the results from TableA.Effective_Date to print in TableB.Fee_Sched_Eff

I am assuming I would use a join or union and possibly an IF statement (if tableA.TIN = tableB.TIN, then print tableA.fee_sched and TableA.Effective_Date). But, I am not sure how I designate which column the results should stored in or how to organize the code correctly.

```
**Example:**
Table A
TIN  Fee_Sched  Effective_Date
123  ABCEDF     1/1/2011
456  ZYXABC     9/9/2009

TABLE B
TIN  Fee_Sched  Fee_Sched_Eff
123  blank      blank

**Results:**
TABLE B
TIN  Fee_Sched  Fee_Sched_Eff
123  ABCEDF     1/1/2011
```

I've tried this:

```
Insert INTO dbo.TableB (Fee_Sched, Fee_Sched_Eff) 
SELECT Fee_Sched, Effective_Date 
FROM dbo.TableA Where dbo.TableA.TIN = dbo.TableB.TIN;
```

But, I get this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The multi-part identifier
>   "dbo.TableB.TIN" could not be bound.

Comment: @nweg

  Insert INTO dbo.TableB (Fee_Sched, Fee_Sched_Eff)
  SELECT Fee_Sched, Effective_Date FROM dbo.TableA
  Where dbo.TableA.TIN = dbo.TableB.TIN;

But, I get this error: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The multi-part identifier "dbo.TableB.TIN" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four basic verbs/actions in SQL:

- `select` retrieves data
- `insert` adds data
- `delete` removes data
- `update` changes data.

`Update` is the one you need to use. With MS SQL you can achieve your desired result using this `update` query:

```
update b
set b.Fee_Sched = a.Fee_Sched, b.Fee_Sched_Eff = Effective_Date
from TableB b
join TableA a on a.TIN = b.TIN
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! When joining these two tables, is there a reason why table B was included in the FROM clause and not table A? If table A was listed in the FROM clause (and the appropriate changes were made in the query), would the same results be populated?

Comment: Using `from a join b` or `from b join a` doesn't matter - I used `b` in from out of habit; the important thing is that there is a join.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first things first: if you want to modify table B, you are looking for an UPDATE command. Also, notice that you can use a SELECT inside the UPDATE statement, and you can reference the "outer" table from inside the SELECT. This should do the trick:

update B set B.fee_sched = (SELECT fee_sched FROM A WHERE A.TIN=B.TIN)

Finally, remember to always post which RDBMS you are using, as there may be differences on what you can write for each of them (Microsoft SQL, Oracle, MySQL?)

Comment: Thanks! I am using Microsoft SQL. 

I got the following error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Well, then you have a problem. You should declare the TIN column as UNIQUE in table A. If it is not UNIQUE, there might be more than one line in A that matches a single line in B.